# Magento 2 - Get Invoice data using observer

Tags: magento2, admin, event-observer, invoice, create-invoice

I am trying to know if create shipment option is selected from admin while creating invoice from admin by creating an observer.
I have tried

```
sales_order_invoice_register
sales_order_invoice_save_after
```

events .
My observer is :

```
<?php

namespace Nmaespace\Module\Observer;

class Invoice implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

/**
 * Execute observer.
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
    $do_shipment = $invoice->getData('do_shipment');
echo $do_shipment;exit;

}

}
```

After all di compile and everything when i try to create an invoice i am getting empty value here . 
Can someone please help me how check this.

Comment: your code is right but problem is not calling your observer so you can check your extension created is perfect or not

Comment: extension is proper .i am able to print other static values in the observer while creating invoice from backend

Comment: what should 'do_shipment' be? I have never heard about such a property of a invoice. Try printing `$invoice->getIncrementId()` and see what happens

Comment: while creating invoice we have a checkbox to create shipment at the same time . That checkbox value i am assuming it be present in 'do_shipment' .

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, guess you're trying to get that "do_shipment" value from the form. Right ?

Comment: you can try this way `$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();`

Comment: It would be better to change your question to what your real problem is, it's not accessing the invoice in the observer. Working with post parameter in observer is not really a good practice. Also be aware that you will access sales_order_invoice_save_after more than once in an invoice's lifetime

Comment: @HelgeB it is accesing the observer . What I really want is to know if create shippment option is selected or not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
In your observer

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;                                       
class Classname implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface        
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {     
        $postdata = $this->_request->getPost();
        $do_shipment = $postdata['invoice']['do_shipment']; 
        echo $do_shipment;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I had to call $postdata['invoice']['do_shipment'] and got